# Select list populated by ajax not opening all options on first click

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I am populating the options of a select list when the user clicks on the select menu.

The options populates fine, but on the first click, only 1 item displays, I have to then click another time to get the full list of values appear in the popup.

[First click image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2dY3.png)

[Second click image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxMZx.png)

Here is the code

```
$('.requestedQuantity').focus(function (e) {      
    ...

    if ($this.val()) {

        if (!$this.data('hasitems')) {

            var selectedValue = $this.val();

            var url = ...

            var params = {
                ...
            }

            $this
                .empty()
                .append($('<option></option')
                    .attr('value', '')
                    .text('Loading...'));

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                data: params,
                contentType: "application/json;",
                success: function (data) {

                    $this.empty()
                        .data('hasitems', 'true');

                    var min = data.Min
                    var max = data.Stock
                    var multiple = data.Multiple
                    var qtyItems = [];

                    for (var i = min; i <= max; i += multiple) {
                        qtyItems.push(i);
                    }

                    $.each(qtyItems, function(index, item) {
                        $this.append($('<option></option>')
                            .val(item)
                            .text(item));
                        if (selectedValue == item) {
                            $this.prop("selectedIndex", index);
                        }
                    });  

                },
                error: function () {
                    //to do
                }
            });

        }

    }       



});
```

I'm wondering whether the options aren't populating in time before the window opens the first time?

Comment: @neilbennett Can you please try an asynch : false on your ajax get?

Comment: @kblau Yes that does solve the issue thanks. Will this now cause the UI to be slightly more unresponsive though?  Is there no way to guarantee all the options are populated before it opens whilst keeping it asynchronous? Thanks

Comment: As far as unresponsive, I don't think this is an issue with modern browsers running on modern pc's.  But I will look further.

Comment: I will try a jquery ready